# Confused About MailTo Character Length

Tags: html, http, email, url

I am using mailto in my application to open email templates in outlook, however sometimes I notice my text is truncated. I can't seem to figure out what is the exact length of characters I can pass and does limit include the syntax part?

For instance I have
      mailto:developer1@kodyaz.com&subject=Mail To Syntax with Samples&body=Hi,%0AIn this    article you will find samples about how to use MailTo in HTML

How many characters would the above be? And does %0A count as a single character or 3?

Thanks

Ronita

Answer (score 0):

First, use http://shadow2531.com/js/mailtouri.html to create mailto URIs and make sure you use UTF-8 for your pages.

As for the length issues, that depends on how the mailto URI is being passed to Outlook. If a browser is using ShellExecute() or CreateProcess() for example, the length limit might be a little less than 32K. If system(), is being used, I'm not sure. If the [MAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Application_Programming_Interface) is used, length probably won't matter at all. However, Outlook might have its own limits.

As for %0D, that would count as 3 characters as far as length limits of the mailto URI go. For a body value, it'd count as one (or two if it's normalized to \r\n). But, not sure if Outlook has a body value limit when the value comes from a mailto URI.

In general though, you shouldn't have a problem.

I'd start testing for the limit by passing mailto URIs of various lengths to outlook.exe to see where the cutoff is. Just make sure the test mailto URIs are properly-encoded and make sure they're properly quoted on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is such restrication apply to mailto tag. Yes there may be some restrication applied by organisation.

%0A will be connsider as single character.